# Xamarin IOS WebView OverrideUrlLoading

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a web page and when I go to it it redirects to a few pages and comes back. Meanwhile, I need to check some fields with queryString. I got this job done for Xamarin.Android. ShouldOverrideUrlLoading method worked for me. I prepared the webview for Xamarin.IOS but I couldn't use a method like ShouldOverrideUrlLoading.

i was try it for xamarin.andriod

```
public class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    private WebView WebViewLogin;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        WebViewLogin = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.WebViewLogin);
        ........
        WebViewLogin.LoadUrl("https://samplelogin.com");
        WebViewLogin.SetWebViewClient(new TeletipWebViewClient());
    }
}



 public class CustomWebViewClient : WebViewClient
    {
        public CustomWebViewClient()
        {
            
        }
        public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, IWebResourceRequest request)
        {
            string url = request.Url.ToString();
            if(url.Contains("loginok")){}//Gratz...
            view.LoadUrl(url);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

And I'm done for android. The code above worked. But I couldn't find what to do for Xamarin.IOS. I have WebView loaded but I can't catch the event when the Url address changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see [webCView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:decisionHandler:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wknavigationdelegate/1455641-webview?language=objc) in `WKNavigationDelegate`. API: [WKNavigationDelegate.DecidePolicy Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/webkit.wknavigationdelegate.decidepolicy?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12#webkit-wknavigationdelegate-decidepolicy(webkit-wkwebview-webkit-wknavigationaction-system-action((webkit-wknavigationactionpolicy))))

For example:

```
   wKWebView.NavigationDelegate = new CustomWkWebViewNavigationDelegate();
//set delegate for the webview. You can find your WKWeview on the ViewController.
//With Xamarin.Forms, you should find the native WKWeview in WkWebViewRenderer
```

**Customize WKNavigationDelegate**

```
 public class CustomWkWebViewNavigationDelegate : WKNavigationDelegate
    {
        public override void DecidePolicy(WKWebView webView, WKNavigationAction navigationAction, Action<WKNavigationActionPolicy> decisionHandler)
        {
            NSUrlRequest request = navigationAction.Request;
            string urlString = request.Url.AbsoluteString;
            if (urlString.Contains("loginok")) {
                decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicy.Allow);
            }else{
                decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicy.Cancel);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was try it, and this works.

```
WebViewLogin.AddObserver("URL", NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, (obs) =>
{
   NSObject test = obs.NewValue;
   string url = test.ToString();
});
```